# Show Outlook contact card in WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, contacts

I am working on a WPF app (written in C#) that searches and serves data from the active directory. Searching for a user will fetch all phone numbers for the user and display on the app window.

How can I open the outlook contact card by the click of some icon or the username or something?

[image: A dummy contact card]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Outlook Contact Card is part of Microsoft Outlook and (as far as I know) not a public control, so you can not simply 'open' it unless you are creating an Outlook add-in.

Using the Active Directory's information you could recreate it.

Answer (score 1):

By Outlook Contact Card I assume you mean a vCard (*.VCF file). It is actually nothing more than a text file. You can easily recreate it. For example:

Create a StringBuilder instance and write the contents of the .VCF file to it.

```
var vcf = new StringBuilder();
vcf.Append("TITLE:" + contact.Title + System.Environment.NewLine); 
//...
```

Afterwards you can save it to a file.

```
var filename = @"C:\mycontact.vcf";
File.WriteAllText(filename, vcf.ToString());
```

Most properties are easy to figure out.

A small example:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
FN:Mr. John Smith
TITLE:Developer
ORG:Microsoft
BDAY:1979-12-10
VERSION:2.1
END:VCARD
```

If you want to include an image you have to base 64 encode it.

If you open this newly created file:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\mycontact.vcf");
```

Then it should be opened by the application that is configured by default to handle this file extension.

Wikipedia contains more information about the contents of a vCard:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard

Comment: No, not a VCard. I want something like this: http://support.microsoft.com/library/images/support/kbgraphics/Public/en-us/office/981022_ss01.png

SharePoint shows this contact card when you hover on a username.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that outlook is using a Lync Feature.
Even if not exactly the Same you can use the Lync SDK in your wpf app if you use Lync.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/uc14trainingcourse_2l_topic2#_Toc273951814